# What is the cause of this error in mini-httpd in an ROS project?

Tags: ros, mini-httpd

the error:

> [mini_httpd-2] process has died [pid 6395, exit code 127, cmd
> /home/santiago/catkin_ws/src/map_nav_manager/scripts/mini-httpd.sh
> __name:=mini_httpd __log:=/home/santiago/.ros/log/53d109f0-aaae-11ea-83ba-7085c2b46229/mini_httpd-2.log].
> log file:
> /home/santiago/.ros/log/53d109f0-aaae-11ea-83ba-7085c2b46229/mini_httpd-2*.log

code in mini-httpd.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh 

# Run the mini-httpd webserver on the port defined in the
# mini-httpd.conf file and set the document directory to the current
# directory

PID=`pidof mini-httpd`

if [ ! -z $PID ]; then
    kill $PID
fi

sleep 1

echo "Launching mini-httpd..."

/usr/sbin/mini-httpd -C `rospack find map_nav_manager`/scripts/mini-httpd.conf -d `rospack find map_nav_manager`
```

code in mini-httpd.conf:

```
# Example config for mini_httpd.
# Author: Marvin Stark <marv@der-marv.de>

# Uncomment this line for turning on ssl support.
#ssl

# On which host mini_httpd should bind?
host=*

# On which port mini_httpd should listen?
port=8181

# Which user mini_httpd should use?
user=nobody

# Run in chroot mode?
#chroot # yes
nochroot # no

# Working directory of mini_httpd.
#dir=<work_dir>

# We are the web files stored?
# Please change this to your needs.
data_dir=./web/

# CGI path
cgipat=cgi-bin/*

# Which certificate to use?
#certfile=<certfile>

# Which logfile to use?
#logfile=

# Which pidfile to use?
#pidfile=/dev/null

# Which charset to use?
charset=iso-8859-1"
```

Does anyone know what the mistake might be?

Answer (score -2):

What does the log say?

Maybe the user nobody doesn't have permission to read or access /home/santiago/catkin_ws/src/map_nav_manager/./web/.

Comment: Speculation is not an accepted reply for an answer. Please try to post responses that with information that you actually know or has being tested to work.